# Select for given description below

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

Having a table like

### id   | Customer | Dept

1986 | Bob      | HR
1986 | Bob      | Admin
2000 | Steve    | HR
2001 | Bob      | Crt
2001 | Bob      | Admin
2005 | Grave    | Dev
2005 | Grave    | Dev

And Want Output like

### id   | Customer | Dept  | Seq | code

1986 | Bob      | HR    | 0   | Bob
1986 | Bob      | Admin | 0   |
2000 | Steve    | HR    | 0   | Steve 
2001 | Bob      | Crt   | 1   | Bob-01 
2001 | Bob      | Admin | 1   |
2005 | Grave    | Dev   | 0   | Dev 
2005 | Grave    | Dev   | 0   |

Seq is:- if we have id and customer same then the Seq should be 0 and if id will be change then seq will be increase by one

Code is combination of name and seq but for the second time if name and id is same then code should be blank

Is it possible .. can anyone please help me?

Comment: Can you describe what the rules are for `seq` and `code`?

Comment: `can anyone please help me?`, maybe if you explain how the other 2 columns are supposed to be calculated

Comment: Seq is:-  if we have id and customer same then the  Seq should be 0 and if id will be  change then seq will be increase by one

Comment: Please edit the question with the detail provided.

Comment: Code is combination of name and seq but for the second time if name and id is same then code should be blank

Answer (score 1):

The code appears to be the "first" time that a name appears for each id.  The sequence appears to be enumerating the ids for each name.

```
select id, Customer, Dept, seq,
       (case when seqnum = 1 then name + '-' + right('0' + cast(seq as varchar(255)), 2)
        end) as code
from (select t.*,
       (rank() over (partition by name order by id) - 1) as seq,
             row_number() over (partition by name, id order by id) as seqnum
      from table t
     ) t;
```

Note that you do have a way of specifying the ordering of the rows, so the code can be on any particular row for a given id.